# How do I get the "Well Informed" Achievement in Cities : Skylines?

Tags: achievements, cities-skylines

The achievement says:

> **Well Informed**
>
> Have a look at all the different info-view panels

This seems to be straight forward, but I somehow cannot manage to get it unlocked. Does anyone have a list of all info-view panels that need to be looked at in order to get this achievement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the **Top Left** of your Screen you can see the Information Box which renderes several Inforamtions directly on the map e.g. Traffic flow.

Simply click through all of them and you get the Achievment.

[image]